# Foreach for class with two template types

Tags: c#, class, foreach, ienumerable, ienumerator

I have my own template class, how to make the foreach loop work for it. I understand how to do this for a template class with one template type, but for two - I do not understand. I understand that you need to inherit from IEnumerable and IEnumerator, but I can't find a suitable example and don't understand what to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CCS8
{
    public class Node<KEY, VALUE>
    {
        public Node(KEY k, VALUE v)
        {
            this.k = k;
            this.v = v;
        }
        public KEY k { get; set; }
        public VALUE v { get; set; }
        public Node<KEY, VALUE> Next { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyList<K, V>
    {
        Node<K, V> head;
        Node<K, V> tail;
        int count;
        int possition = -1;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (possition < count - 1)
            {
                possition++;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            possition = -1;
        }

        public void Add(K k, V v)
        {
            Node<K, V> node = new Node<K, V>(k, v);

            if (head == null)
                head = node;
            else
                tail.Next = node;
            tail = node;

            count++;
        }
        public int Count { get { return count; } }

        public V ValueByIndex(int i)
        {
            int j = 0;
            Node<K, V> current = head;
            while (j != i)
            {
                current = current.Next;
                j++;
            }
            return current.v;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyList<int, String> l = new MyList<int, String>();
            // добавление элементов
            l.Add(1, "Line1");
            l.Add(2, "Line2");
            l.Add(3, "Line3");
            l.Add(4, "Line4");

            Console.WriteLine("3th elemnt: " + l.ValueByIndex(2));
            Console.WriteLine("Elements count: " + l.Count);

            foreach (var i in l)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us start at the beginning - what exactly do you want to achieve? Something like "your list" already exists and is called [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0). E.g. if you would iterate over a dictionary, you would get instances of [KeyValuePair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=net-5.0).

Comment: In .NET, "templates" are generally referred to as "generics". You may have an easier time searching using that term.

Comment: I want to output the keys and values of the class through the cycle foreach